# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception flutter error . help me

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, authentication

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
> Required by:
> project :app

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed adding the platforms.

```
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
 implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx")
```